# How to deploy golang application on gcloud

Tags: go, gcloud

Hi i am trying to deploy a golang application on gcloud using command on ubuntu:-

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml index.yaml
```

But i am getting an error as follow:-

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed: /work_dir/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert/assertions.go:17: can't find import: "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew" 2018/01/02 04:59:26 go-app-builder: build timing: 23×compile (14.75s total), 0×link (0s total) 2018/01/02 04:59:26 go-app-builder: failed running compile: exit status 2
```

I have installed all the dependencies and packages please help me thanx in advance :)

Comment: Did you also install `github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew`? Can you locate it in your `vendor` folder. Do you have a `vendor` folder in your project?

Comment: No, I do not have vendor directory in my project. My project is in the directory /home/go/src/bitbucket.org/bigkittylabs.com/uout-go and I have installed "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew" in src folder. please help me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gcloud but I suspect you need to *vendor your dependencies*, search the internet for `go dep` or `govendor`, or some other go dependency management tool and go from there.

Comment: @mkopriva I used govander on running govander init and govendor add +external.
Now I have a vendor directory inside my project.
But I am still unable to deploy it because I am getting different error

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
2018/01/03 00:39:14 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: package "bitbucket.org/bigkittylabs/uout-go/vendor/golang.org/x/oauth2" cannot import internal package "golang.org/x/oauth2/internal"

Comment: (https://github.com/kardianos/govendor#package-specifier) Try `govendor add golang.org/x/oaut‌​h2/^`, although I think the internal package should have been vendored automatically...

Comment: Also take a look at this https://github.com/kardianos/govendor/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud` is broken: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38449183 try to use `goapp`.